# signed integer overflow: 1111111111111111111 * 10 cannot be represented in type 'long long'

Tags: c

```
int get_dnum(long long ccn,int di){
    long long x=1;
    for(int y=1;y<di;y++){
    x=x*(long long)10;
    }
    return ccn%x;
```

The x is a long long.The 10 is a long long.How does this error happen?

- runtime error: signed integer overflow: 1111111111111111111 * 10
  cannot be represented in type 'long long'

Comment: You probably mean to increment `y` in the for statement, not `x`.

Comment: 600 ml of water can fit into one liter bottle. 500 ml can fit in 1 liter bottle. How is that 600 ml and 500 ml can't fit in 1 liter bottle?

Comment: `long long` (which is signed, by default) is supposed to be (at least) 64 bits in length, meaning that the maximum representable number is (at least) +9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (i.e. 2^63-1). The number you've specified, 1,111,111,111,111,111,111 is less than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, and thus fits in a signed `long long`. However, your number multiplied by 10 exceeds the max value for a signed `long long`. If you declare `x` to be of type `unsigned long long` then the multiplication you specified should work. Best of luck.

Comment: Thank you.I think I understand it now.

Comment: @BobJarvis Would you like to make that an answer? Sounds like a decent , if not world-shaking, Q/A pair.

Comment: @Yunnosch - done.

Answer (score 0):

`long long` (which is signed, by default) is supposed to be (at least) 64 bits in length, meaning that the maximum representable number is (at least) +9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (i.e. 2^63-1). The number you've specified, 1,111,111,111,111,111,111 is less than 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, and thus fits in a signed `long long`. However, your number multiplied by 10 exceeds the max value for a 64-bit signed `long long`. If you declare x to be of type `unsigned long long` then the multiplication you specified should work.

Best of luck.

Comment: "However, your number multiplied by 10 exceeds the max value for a 64-bit signed long long." should be followed with ".. and that is _undefined behavior_." A sample _undefined behavior_ is a runtime error.  Using _unsigned long long_ does prevent the math overflow, yet even if it did math overflow, there would be no _undefined behavior_ as _unsigned_ overflow is specified to "wrap".

Comment: Harvard, MIT, Dartmouth, Yale, and several other universities recently announced a new area of specialization which would combine work in the computer science departments and law schools. This new program would train individuals in the details of the C and C++ language standards in their many and varying incarnations. The stated purpose of this combined degree program is to "...to increase the knowledge of these important languages, and to afford more opportunties for informed discussion, argument, and vendetta regarding them". The new degree would tentatively be referred to as an ll_c.